# How to use environment variable in an Azure template without modifying the template in Azure pipelines

Tags: azure, azure-devops, azure-pipelines

I'm trying to set up a pipeline where template is used which has to consume some environment variables defined on a runner. The problematic points are:

1. Environment variables that are defined on a runner cannot be renamed and environment variables that template expects also cannot be renamed. Names of the variables differ.
2. Template cannot be modified.

I tried using

```
- job: Build
  ...
  steps:
  ...
  - powershell: |
      Write-Host "##vso[task.setvariable variable=TEMPLATE_VAR_A;]$(var_a)"
      Write-Host "##vso[task.setvariable variable=TEMPLATE_VAR_B;]$(var_b)"
    name: setEnvVars

# run tests
- template: execute-tests.yml
```

var_a and var_b are defined on the runner and TEMPLATE_VAR_A and TEMPLATE_VAR_B are used in the tests, so I need some way of assigning var_a and var_b to TEMPLATE_VAR_A and TEMPLATE_VAR_B.

Unfortunately, after executing a run with this change, TEMPLATE_VAR_A and TEMPLATE_VAR_B are still empty during the job execution inside of execute-tests.yml.

Comment: Hi @Kreso, variables cannot simply be invoked in next job/agent. Hence you can check the `expanded yaml` to confirm your real yaml structure. I added the details in the reply below, thanks.

Comment: Thanks, when checking full YAML I found out that setting of the variable and consuming the variable is done in the same job, it was just syntax that needed to be fixed. However your explanation was still valuable and I learned from it.

Comment: Glad to know it's resolved and the answer helps! Happy coding!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As per your yaml format, the template is align with job build, hence it's a `job level template`. You can click "Download full Yaml" to check the expanded yaml.

[image]

Different jobs are run on different agents, you cannot simply invoke the variables from job1 in job2. You have to modify the main yaml and template yaml.

1. In main yaml, add `isoutput=true` when you define the variable.

```
pool:
  vmImage: ubuntu-latest

jobs:
 - job: Build
    steps:
    - powershell: |
        Write-Host "##vso[task.setvariable variable=TEMPLATE_VAR_A;isoutput=true]$(var_a)"
        Write-Host "##vso[task.setvariable variable=TEMPLATE_VAR_B;isoutput=true]$(var_b)"
      name: setEnvVars

  # run tests
 - template: execute-tests.yml
```

- In template yaml, you need to redefine the variable, to use the variable from previous job. (Note: you can also define parameter and use parameter value as variable value in template)

```
jobs:
- job: test
  dependsOn: build
  variables:
    TEMPLATE_VAR_A: $[ dependencies.build.outputs['setEnvVars.TEMPLATE_VAR_A'] ]
    TEMPLATE_VAR_B: $[ dependencies.build.outputs['setEnvVars.TEMPLATE_VAR_B'] ]
  steps:
  - bash: |
      echo $(TEMPLATE_VAR_A)
      echo $(TEMPLATE_VAR_B)
```

[image]

You can check the official [doc](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/pipelines/process/variables?view=azure-devops&tabs=yaml%2Cbatch#set-a-multi-job-output-variable) for more detials.

Another option, you can define the template in `step` level, in this scenario, the tasks are executes in same agent, you can directly invoke the variables.

Main yaml, notice the template is aligned with steps.

```
pool:
  vmImage: ubuntu-latest

jobs:
  - job: Build
    steps:
    - powershell: |
        Write-Host "##vso[task.setvariable variable=TEMPLATE_VAR_A]$(var_a)"
        Write-Host "##vso[task.setvariable variable=TEMPLATE_VAR_B]$(var_b)"
      name: setEnvVars

    # run tests
    - template: execute-tests2.yml
```

Template yaml:

```
steps:
- bash: |
   echo $(TEMPLATE_VAR_A)
   echo $(TEMPLATE_VAR_B)
```

Only one job is this case:

[image]